# Tumbling Window Trigger cancel past executions Azure data factory

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory

We have a requirement to use tumbling window trigger because of the retry policy but our prod deployment will happen after 1 month of dev deployment and we don't want to manually kill these 30 execution in production because of the functionality of tumbling window trigger to run those missed days. Is there a way we can avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this too but the documentation states:

> **Execution order of windows in a backfill scenario**
>
> If the startTime of trigger is in the past, then based on this
> formula, `M=(CurrentTime- TriggerStartTime)/TumblingWindowSize`, the
> trigger will generate {M} backfill(past) runs in parallel, honoring
> trigger concurrency, before executing the future runs. The order of
> execution for windows is deterministic, from oldest to newest
> intervals. *Currently, this behavior can't be modified.*

[Documentation Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-tumbling-window-trigger#execution-order-of-windows-in-a-backfill-scenario)